# OpenGL reflection not mapping skybox correctly

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm trying to learn reflections on OpenGL without using the LearnOpenGL method, but I can't figure out what's wrong with the reflections. There seems to be some sort of warping and flipping happening at certain parts of the camera view. So far, I'm just using a view matrix to simply the code.

This is how the sphere reflections looks like.

[image]

I also tried using a cube. Even when my mouse continued to move right, the reflection warped and then ended up showing the image that was present before the warping.

Cube reflection

[image]

Skybox image

[image]

This is the skybox vertex shader

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

out vec3 o_pos;

void main()
{
    o_pos = aPos;
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
}
```

This is the skybox fragment shader. I pass the view matrix directly to the fragment shader.

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 o_pos;

uniform vec3 view_up;
uniform vec3 view_right;
uniform vec3 view_forward;

uniform samplerCube cubeTex;

void main()
{
    vec3 pv = mat3(view_right, view_up, view_forward) * vec3(o_pos.xy, 1.0);
    FragColor = vec4(texture(cubeTex, pv).rgb, 1.0);
}
```

This is the object vertex shader

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 normal;

out vec3 o_normal;
out vec3 o_pos;

void main()
{
    o_pos = aPos;
    o_normal = normal;
    gl_Position = vec4(o_pos, 1.0f);
}
```

This is the object fragment shader. It's similar to the learnopengl shader.

```
#version 330 core
in vec3 o_pos;
in vec3 o_normal;

out vec4 fragColor;

uniform vec3 eye_pos;
uniform samplerCube cubeTex;

void main()
{
    vec3 incident = normalize(o_pos - eye_pos);
    vec3 reflection = reflect(incident, normalize(o_normal));
    fragColor = vec4(texture(cubeTex, reflection).rgb, 1.0);
}
```

Here is the render loop

```
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // input
        processInput(window);

        // render
        glClearColor(0.9f, 0.8f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // change view using mouse input
        double xpos, ypos;
        glfwGetCursorPos(window, &xpos, &ypos);
        ypos = (ypos/SCR_HEIGHT) * PI * PI * 0.5;
        xpos = (xpos/SCR_WIDTH) * 2 * PI - PI;
        if (ypos < PI/2) ypos = 1.6f;
        if (ypos > 3*PI/2) ypos = 4.7f;
        eye_forward = normalize(glm::vec3{(GLfloat)(cos(ypos) * cos(xpos)),
                                (GLfloat)sin(ypos),
                                (GLfloat)(cos(ypos) * sin(xpos))});
        eye_right = glm::normalize(glm::cross(eye_forward, glm::vec3{0.0, 1.0, 0.0}));
        eye_up = glm::cross(eye_right, eye_forward);

        // draw skybox
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glUniform1i(u_cubeTex, 0);
        glUniform3fv(u_view_up, 1, (GLfloat*)&eye_up);
        glUniform3fv(u_view_right, 1, (GLfloat*)&eye_right);
        glUniform3fv(u_view_forward, 1, (GLfloat*)&eye_forward);
        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, cube.size());

        // draw UV sphere
        glUseProgram(sphereProgram);
        glUniform1i(u_cubeTex2, 0);
        glUniform3fv(u_eye_pos, 1, (GLfloat*)&eye_forward);
        glBindVertexArray(sphereVAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE, 0, sphere.size());

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eye_pos` is a position in world space.
`o_pos` is a position in view space, clip space  and normalized device space. This is all the same in your case, because you don't have a projection matrix and the vertex coordinate attribute is directly assigned to the clip space position in the vertex shader:

> ```
>  gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
> ```

Anyway, it doesn't make any sense to calculate a vector from a world space position to a view space position, as you do it:

> ```
>  vec3 incident = normalize(o_pos - eye_pos);
> ```

The eye position in view space is (0, 0, 0). So the incident view vector in view space is:

```c
vec3 incident = normalize(o_pos - vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
```

This vector has to be transformed form view space to world space, which can be achieved by the orientation matrix of the view (`mat3(view_right, view_up, view_forward)`), in the same way as you do it in the skybox fragment shader:

```c
vec3 incident = mat3(view_right, view_up, view_forward) * normalize(o_pos);
```

The normal vector `o_normal` is a view space vector, too. So it has to be transformed to world space:

```c
vec3 wordlNormal = mat3(view_right, view_up, view_forward) * normalize(o_normal);
```

Instead of transforming the the incident vector and the normal vector, it is possible to transform the resulting vector after the reflection.
You have to change the object fragment shader, to solve your issue:

```c
#version 330 core

in vec3 o_pos;
in vec3 o_normal;

out vec4 fragColor;

uniform vec3 view_up;
uniform vec3 view_right;
uniform vec3 view_forward;
uniform samplerCube cubeTex;

void main()
{
    mat3 invNormalM      = mat3(view_right, view_up, view_forward);

    vec3 viewIncident    = normalize(o_pos);
    vec3 viewNormal      = normalize(o_normal);
    vec3 worldReflection = invNormalM * reflect(viewIncident, viewNormal);

    fragColor            = vec4(texture(cubeTex, worldReflection).rgb, 1.0);
}
```

---

> I pass the view matrix directly to the fragment shader.

`mat3(view_right, view_up, view_forward)` is not the view matrix. It is orientation matrix of the camera. So it is the inverse view (normal) matrix.